# Can you download Xcode on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can you download Xcode on **iPhone**?

Comment: You can _create_ apps for the iPhone in Xcode on a Macintosh computer, though.

Answer (score 4):

Briefly, no.

Xcode is OS X only. You **must** have a Mac to download Xcode.